# how to detect dom elements changes in Anglesharp

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, html-parser, anglesharp

I'm parsing the web-site using Anglesharp - and everything works fine
But some information is shown only after clicking elements on the page and it happens on the fly
In browsers I can see those changes, but when I parse Anglesharp is not able to load DOM elements changes
How to detect changes using Anglesharp and parse data from new elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Those changes created by javascript and did not exist in original source code that sent you from web server. Anglesharp or HTMLAgilityPack does not execute javascript code and only parse original source code.

You need an actual web browser to execute js code. As far as I know you can use Selenium WebDriver or Chromium Browser which gives you the ability to interact with web browser.